# Change decimal number in excel to format of python (spyder)

Tags: python, excel, timestamp, decimal

I am so sorry, i  have this problem:

```
archivo = 'LB2018.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo) 
dias = []
hoja = wb.sheet_by_name('LB2018') 
for i in range(0,hoja.nrows):
   
    dias.append(hoja.cell_value(i,0))
    
print(dias)
```

The column it extracts are real decimal values, which I want to change to timestamp format, but I don't know what function to use to do it, the format of the excel is like that:

[image]

Comment: use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). example: `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"); timestamp = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date);` this should give you the corresponding timestamp value, to put in your `for-loop`.

Comment: import xlrd 
archivo = 'LB2018.xlsx'
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo) 
dias = []
hoja = wb.sheet_by_name('LB2018') 
for i in range(0,hoja.nrows):
   dias = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M");
   timestamp = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date)
   dias.append(hoja.cell_value(i,0))
print(dias)

Comment: i am putting like that but i have an error...

Comment: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'dt'